# Compiling with clang with c++11 enabled fails

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, clang

Having the following `test.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
        int a{};
        std::cout << "TEST" << std::endl;
}
```

When build with the latest GCC (4.8.0) `g++ test.cpp -std=c++11` (gcc also fails), the file compiles. Trying to compile with the latest clang

```
clang version 3.4 (trunk 182322)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

the build fails:

```
clang test.cpp -std=c++11 

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))", referenced from:
      _main in test-NcubkF.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in test-NcubkF.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in test-NcubkF.o
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      _main in test-NcubkF.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      _main in test-NcubkF.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in test-NcubkF.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What can be done for `clang` (or `gcc`) to work in C++11 mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`clang` is for C.  For C++, use `clang++`.

```
clang++ test.cpp -std=c++11
```

Comment: Thank you, seems pretty obvious now.